# how to prevent cross site scripting - Image is linked

Tags: php, xss

XSS

[image]

can you help me with thid cross site scripting i am new in this

Comment: Look up CSP - Not the Chartered Society of Physiotherapists (although they're very good) but *Content Security Policy*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-site scripting is a code injection attack.

The problem is that the user (or someone else) enters a script instead of some input value. For example, a user puts a "<script>" tag in her comment.

If you then display a list of comments, that script will be executed for anyone visiting that page.

What you need to do is sanitize the outputs, that is, remove or escape all html code that you're writing on a page. That way, the `<script>` tag will be replaced with `&lt;script&gt;`, and it will become harmless while *looking* exactly the same.

Comment: I am using this to print message to user who submit form is there error in this that is showing cross site scripting??


`echo "<script> alert('ThankYou For Your Interest $name'); </script>";`

Comment: It's the $name that you're not filtering. Suppose someone enters the name:  `'); doNastyStuff(); alert('You got owned, mate!`

Comment: A solution would be to put a \ before all single quotes in $name, though there are probably standard ways to sanitize Javascript strings. This is actually a very similar attack to SQL-Injection, but here it happens in the browser rather than a DB.